# Django app on heroku: content wont appear in mobile browser

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

After deploying my django application on heroku i had a weird experience why the application content is fine and working on desktop browsers however in any mobile devices such as android and ios browsers the content wont display. Is there any setup for mobile browser?

Comment: Can you share the URL of your website?

Comment: Are you sure your website is accessible from other devices anyway? You tried to access it from another laptop or in browsers "private mode"? What do you see when you open the page with your phone and if its an error which one is it? You initialized logging for your project?

Comment: @ArpitSvt well im not sure but let me think about it

Comment: Im not sure if it is accessible or not but of course i did make it live with heroku then im expecting to show it in any devices, tried it in both laptop and any desktop device of course it works but only for mobile devices it wont work.

Comment: @ArpitSvt it is rather a web application combining django and angularjs

Comment: Then try debugging your Javascript in Android mobile

Comment: how can i do that im sorry for beginners knowledge

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: It seems that my app is working on android in chrome browser only.